# Regex search a word and select all text in qutoes

Tags: json, regex, web

I have the following html code and i want to search for the file tag 'http://test.com/d/wfne46sgmeikmgi3mg4kfmdgsunj4/video.mp4'. I have tried the following expression 'http[s]?://node(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+' but it doesnt work because sometimes the domain test.com is different so the only thing that is unique is video.mp4. How can i search for video.mp4 and select all the other stuff in quotes?

Thanks for your help

```
p.setup({
        autostart: true,
        file: 'http://test.com/d/wfne46sgmeikmgi3mg4kfmdgsunj4/video.mp4',
        type: 'mp4',
        height: window.innerHeight,
        image: '//cdn.test.com/thumb/hjjjgef.jpg',

        startparam: 'start',
        width: window.innerWidth,
        abouttext:'Player',
        aboutlink: 'http://www.test.com/abc',
        logo: {
            hide: true,
            file: '//cdn.test.com/images/logo.png'
        },
        sharing: {
           code: encodeURI('<iframe width="640" height="360" src="http://test.com/embed-fwahrhsrh.html" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>'),
           link: 'http://www.test.com/fwahrhsrh'
        },
    });
```

Comment: By the way, the expression you posted is pretty much completely unrelated to the pattern you are trying to match...where did you get it?

Comment: sorry youre right its a snippet from a html file so i choose html.i have fixed that

Comment: mostly i have node.test.com/d/......./video.mp4.

Answer (score 1):

To match a quoted string which ends in `video.mp4`, the following snippet should work:

```
'(.*?video\.mp4)'
```

[Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/WzPrTD/1)